# PCIe lanes with multiple cards

Tags: pci-express

So I´m a little confused by something I recently read online and I wasn´t realy able to find any helpful information about this...
Say I have a CPU with 16 PCIe lanes and an x16 GPU  and an x1 network card or something. Will the GPU then run with only 8 lanes, the network card with 1 lane and the other 7 lanes will be unused? Because PCIe can only have either 16 or 8 (or 4, 1 and 32) lanes, right?

I hope this question makes sense

Comment: *"Say I have a CPU with 16 PCIe lanes ..."* -- PCIe is not part of the CPU, but the motherboard.  *"Will the GPU then run with only 8 lanes ..."* -- No, all the PCIe lanes of each PCIe connector (aka slot) are dedicated to just that connector.  The PCIe lanes of one connector/device are not shared with any other connector/device.  The key concept of PCIe is that it does not have a shared bus.  The (total) number of PCIe lanes that a motherboard has is the ***sum*** of PCIe lanes for each connector/slot, and not just the largest connector/slot as you misunderstand.

Comment: can you update your question with  the model name  of your cpu & motherboard ?

Comment: @sawdust an Intel i9 9900k for example has 16 PCIe lanes, so the number of possible lanes must have something to do with the CPU, right?

Comment: @EchoMike444 let´s say for example an Intel core i9 990k with an asus ws z390 pro

Comment: @abcd plus update the question , because commens can be confusing .

Comment: *"so the number of possible lanes must have something to do with the CPU, right?"* -- The total number of PCIe lanes is determined by the motherboard.  When the CPU has PCIe lanes, then the mobo will route the lanes of the GPU slot to the CPU (for optimal performance). The remaining PCIe lanes would be routed to the motherboard's PCIe switch, which would be part of the mobo chipset (e.g. the PCH, Platform Controller Hub).  These lanes connected to the PCH instead of directly to the CPU, in theory, could bottleneck.

Comment: @sawdust aaah okay, got it. Thanks